# Ionic CLI 4.0.1 update has some issues

Tags: ionic2

While running an Ionic application, I'm getting an update message for the latest CLI 4.0.1.

I have updated CLI.  After updating, when I'm running the Ionic app, it's print a message, "CLI closed unexpectedly". I have downgraded to old version, so now its working fine.  To downgrade the CLI version, I ran:

```
npm i -g ionic@3.20.0
```

Is any one facing the same issue that I'mm facing? Or its a Ionic CLI issue for the latest version?

Comment: I've updated the English punctuation and formatting on this question.  I've also indented the actual command you ran to downgrade by 4 spaces so that it renders properly; please see [the editing help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) for more help on formatting.

Answer (score 1):

- you can downgrade to your old version by running: npm i -g ionic@3.20.0